# Did any early church Christian writers ever place Origen in a early martyrology or menologium?

Tags: catholicism, eastern-orthodox, reference-request, martyrdom, origen

**Did any early church Christian writers ever place Origen in a early [martyrology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martyrology) or [menologium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menologium)?**

There are many early [Church Fathers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church_Fathers). Some are canonized saints, while some are not. Origen is not without controversy in his writings, motivations and actions. Yet one can not deny that he genuinely believed in Jesus Christ and was more than willing to suffer death for his belief in God.

> Origen, most modest of writers, hardly ever alludes to himself in his own works; but Eusebius has devoted to him almost the entire sixth book of "Ecclesiastical History".
>
> Finally, at a much later period, under Pontian of Rome and Zebinus of Antioch (Eusebius, VI, xxiii), he journeyed into Greece, passing through Caesarea where Theoctistus, Bishop of that city, assisted by Alexander, Bishop of Jerusalem, raised him to the priesthood. Demetrius, although he had given letters of recommendation to Origen, was very much offended by this ordination, which had taken place without his knowledge and, as he thought, in derogation of his rights. If Eusebius (VI, viii) is to be believed, he was envious of the increasing influence of his catechist. So, on his return to Alexandria, Origen soon perceived that his bishop was rather unfriendly towards him. He yielded to the storm and quitted Egypt (231). The details of this affair were recorded by Eusebius in the lost second book of the "Apology for Origen"; according to Photius, who had read the work, two councils were held at Alexandria, one of which pronounced a decree of banishment against Origen while the other deposed him from the priesthood (Biblioth. cod. 118). **St. Jerome declares expressly that he was not condemned on a point of doctrine**.
>
> Age did not diminish his activities. He was over sixty when he wrote his "Contra Celsum" and his "Commentary on St. Matthew". The persecution of Decius (250) prevented him from continuing these works. Origen was imprisoned and barbarously tortured, but his courage was unshaken and from his prison he wrote letters breathing the spirit of the martyrs (Eusebius, Church History VI.39). He was still alive on the death of Decius (251), but only lingering on, and he died, probably, from the results of the sufferings endured during the persecution (253 or 254), at the age of sixty-nine (Eusebius, Church History VII.1). His last days were spent at Tyr, though his reason for retiring thither is unknown. He was buried with honour as a confessor of the Faith. **For a long time his sepulchre, behind the high-altar of the cathedral of Tyr**, was visited by pilgrims. Today, as nothing remains of this cathedral except a mass of ruins, the exact location of his tomb is unknown. - [Catholic Encyclopedia](http://www.newadvent.org/cathen/11306b.htm)

There are claims that Origen may have castrated himself, but the claim seems somewhat dubious.

> Eusebius claims that, as a young man, following a literal misreading of Matthew 19:12, in which Jesus is presented as saying "there are eunuchs who have made themselves eunuch for the sake of the kingdom of heaven", Origen went to a physician and paid him to surgically remove his genitals in order to ensure his reputation as a respectable tutor to young men and women. Eusebius further alleges that Origen privately told Demetrius, the bishop of Alexandria, about the castration and that Demetrius initially praised him for his devotion to God on account of it. Origen himself, however, never mentions anything about having castrated himself in any of his surviving writings and, in his exegesis of this verse in his Commentary on the Gospel of Matthew, written near the end of life, he strongly condemns any literal interpretation of Matthew 19:12, asserting that only an idiot would interpret the passage as advocating literal castration.
>
> Since the beginning of the twentieth century, some scholars have questioned the historicity of Origen's self-castration, with many seeing it as a wholesale fabrication. Trigg states that Eusebius's account of Origen's self-castration is certainly true, because Eusebius, who was an ardent admirer of Origen, yet clearly describes the castration as an act of pure folly, would have had no motive to pass on a piece of information that might tarnish Origen's reputation unless it was "notorious and beyond question." Trigg sees Origen's condemnation of the literal interpretation of Matthew 19:12 as him "tacitly repudiating the literalistic reading he had acted on in his youth." [Alleged self-castration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Origen#cite_note-FOOTNOTEMcGuckin20045-39)

Wikipedia goes on to say this about his last years:

> In c. 249, the Plague of Cyprian broke out. In 250, Emperor Decius, believing that the plague was caused by Christians' failure to recognise him as Divine, issued a decree for Christians to be persecuted. This time Origen did not escape.[11][88] Eusebius recounts how Origen suffered "bodily tortures and torments under the iron collar and in the dungeon; and how for many days with his feet stretched four spaces in the stocks". The governor of Caesarea gave very specific orders that Origen was not to be killed until he had publicly renounced in faith in Christ. Origen endured two years of imprisonment and torture, but obstinately refused to renounce his faith. In 252, the emperor Decius was assassinated and Origen was released from prison. Nonetheless, Origen's health was broken by the physical tortures enacted on him and he died less than a year later at the age of sixty-nine. A later legend, recounted by Jerome and numerous itineraries, places his death and burial at Tyre, but little value can be attached to this. - [Origen (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Origen)

Although [Origen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Origen) was a controversial figure in the [Early Church](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Early_Christianity). It seems that he may have been honored as a true martyr within the community of some of the faithful, being buried behind the high-altar of the cathedral at Tyre. His father, [St. Leonides of Alexandria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leonides_of_Alexandria), is recognized as a martyr in the Catholic Church (April 22).

Thus once again I ask: **Does the name of Origen appear on any early martyrology or menologium and if so does it assign a date for his feast?**